# How to put a list of arbitrary integers on screen (from lowest to highest) in pygame proportionally?

Tags: python, math, pygame

Let's say I have a list of 887123, 123, 128821, 9, 233, 9190902. I want to put those strings on screen using pygame (line drawing), and I want to do so proportionally, so that they fit the screen. If the screen is 1280x720, how do I scale the numbers down so that they keep their proportions to each other but fit the screen? 
I did try with techniques such as dividing every number by two until they are all smaller than 720, but that is skewed. Is there an algorithm for this sort of mathematical scaling?

Comment: So that they keep proportions to each other? So `9` has to keep proportion compared to `9190902`? Are you sure about that? It's basically one pixel over a line that goes across all the screen (because `9` is about 0.000001% of `9190902`).

Answer (score 1):

I used this algorithm: x = (x / (maximum value)) * (720 - 1)